# Is it possible to share a hard drive connected by USB in a local network?

Tags: networking

I have an android smart TV with android 4.1, USB and LAN port. For file transfer I have a USB hard drive which I move from my computer to the smart TV, but it is kind of annoying.

I would like to leave the hard drive connected to the smart TV, and share it in my local network so that I can access it from my gnu/linux machine.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run an SSH server app on your Android TV? If yes, then you probably can access the hard drive as well. OTG drives are often  mounted at `/mnt/usbotg`.

Comment: If it is a matter of installing the right application, I guess I can. I will read on these SSH servers, thanks! If you elaborate a short answer that can be useful to other people, I'll be glad to accept it :).

Comment: Thanks, but I'll wait until you confirm that you can install such an app and that it is working for you. :)

Comment: After playing a while with SSHelper, I got it to work. Not very fast, but it does the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Firelord for pointing me in the right direction, I played around with a SSH Server called SSHelper (it's FOSS and can be found on the play store), and got what I was trying to do.

The website has enough information to get it working, and it is very easy to set a passwordless login.

The only con I see, it is that is rather slow for big file transfers.